# Facebook notification post data asp.net

Tags: asp.net, facebook, post, notifications

I created a facebook app. A small game in asp.net mvc. It is a real time turn based game and i want the first player to choose his opponent, send him a facebook notification and go to the page of tthe game.
The second player then clicks on this notification and also go the the page of the game.
My problem is about the href parameter of the post data.
In asp.net i create a webhttprequest object. But my data i have to post is like that :

But when second player click on notification the last two parameters are lost. I think it is because symbol & is used with facebook graph address and with my address. How can i write the correct postdata with all the parameters ??

Here is my code :

```
public string sendnotificationtoplay(string monid, string prenomMoi, string codetokenjeu)
{
    try
    {
        // variables to store parameter values
        string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + monid + "/notifications";
        string autrePrenom = "@[" + monid + "]";
        string texte = "@[" + monid + "] ! " + prenomMoi + " wants to play with you ! \n Click here !";

        // creates the post data for the POST request
        string postData = ("access_token=MYACCESSTOKEN&template=" + texte + "&href=mywebsite.org/Index?ordredemandejeugame=2&codejeuadeux=ds&prenom1=dfdf&prenom2=fdgdfg");

        // create the POST request
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        // POST the data
        using (StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            requestWriter2.Write(postData);
        }

        //  This actually does the request and gets the response back
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        string responseData = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            // dumps the HTML from the response into a string variable
            responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return responseData;`
```

please help me :)

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please include the code that you think contains the problem so we can better understand what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you Robert ! Below is my code :

Comment: I added my code below Robert ! And sorry to all others for my answer posts. This is the first time I use this website to solve a problem.